# Moving an attribute value within an XML-tag to a separate node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to move an attribute value within an XML-element to a new child-element with a different name as the attribute. The value however stays the same, as does the rest of the text within the element. The original XML-line (an extract from the complete XML-message) is:

```
<vanaf a:entiteittype="NPS" a:sleutelOntvangend="xxxxxx1608" xmlns:a="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301"></vanaf>
```

The XML-output I need to create is:

```
<vanaf a:entiteittype="NPS" xmlns:a="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301">
    <inp.a-nummer>xxxxxx1608</inp.a-nummer>
</vanaf>
```

Apart from these lines, the rest of the original XML-message can be copied as-is. So far I have constructed the following code, but without success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:package="info:srw/extension/13/package-v1.0" xmlns:StUF="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:BG="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="BG:vanaf">
    <vanaf a:entiteittype="NPS" xmlns:a="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301">
    <inp.a-nummer> <xsl:value-of select = "@a:SleutelOntvangend"/> </inp.a-nummer>
    </vanaf>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help to point me in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:package="info:srw/extension/13/package-v1.0" 
    xmlns:StUF="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" 
    xmlns:BG="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310"
    exclude-result-prefixes="BG package StUF">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="vanaf">
        <vanaf a:entiteittype="NPS" xmlns:a="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301">
            <inp.a-nummer> <xsl:value-of select = "@a:sleutelOntvangend"/> </inp.a-nummer>
        </vanaf>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

NOTE: 
1. template match having unknown namespace 'BG'
2. Need to exclude extra namespaces which not required in output.
3. In value-of attribute name is wrong: @a:sleutelOntvangend